# How can I get the equation I am calculating to show the user the a value * x to the second power. An error pops up when I try to square x

Tags: ruby, equation

```
puts "Let's get started calculating your parabola. What is your A value?"
a = gets.chomp

puts "What is your B value?"
b = gets.chomp
puts "What is your C value?"
c = gets.chomp
x = x
2x = (x.to_i**2)

puts "Your parabola equation is 'y = " + a.to_s + 2x.to_s + " + " + b.to_s + x + " + " + c.to_s + "'. Would you like to go back to the beginning?"
```

Comment: I do have the a value defined, I just forgot to add that. My problem is to create X as a variable, like you would find in the parabola equation 'y=ax^2 + bx + c". I don't understand how to create it so that "x" is squared so like in a parabola equation. I get an error saying:                                                 calculator2.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
 2x = (x.to_i**2)
   ^
calculator2.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
...quation is 'y = " + a.to_s + 2x.to_s + " + " + b.to_s + x + ...

Comment: If you wish to elaborate your question, you should edit it rather than adding a comment.  Being new to SO, you may wish to read over [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby variable names can't start with a number, but you did it, `2x = (x.to_i**2)`. Write it as `x2 = (x.to_i**2)`. Then replace all `2x` with `x2` in your code.

Another error will be `x=x`, this is also invalid. Hope you mistyped. Correct it also.

Read this [**Local Variable Names**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variable+Names)

> A local variable name must start with a lowercase US-ASCII letter or a character with the eight bit set. Typically local variables are US-ASCII compatible since the keys to type them exist on all keyboards.
>
> (Ruby programs must be written in a US-ASCII-compatible character set. In such character sets if the eight bit is set it indicates an extended character. Ruby allows local variables to contain such characters.)
>
> A local variable name may contain letters, numbers, an _ (underscore or low line) or a character with the eighth bit set.